# how to save or move image file to a folder contain in my php file folder

Tags: php

I'm building a media and I want my users to
 upload as many images as they like,But my problem
 is how to save or move this image to a folder
 called photo contain in folder called my_media,
 my_media folder contain my php files such as
 index.php and more,I can move this file to 
 my_media folder once upload,But i don't want
 the file they for security purpose,please 
 someone should fix my code thanks.

this my code

```
require_once ('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

 $tmp_dir = "my_media/photo";
 //it will move to my_media if assign my_media only to the variable $tmp_dir
 //but don't work with  $tmp_dir = "my_media/photo"

 $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
 $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$tmp_dir . basename($name));

    //rename("my_media/photo","my_media/photo". basename($name));
$location=$name;
$fname=$_POST['first_name'];
$lname=$_POST['last_name'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_image (first_name, last_name, image_location)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$location')";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
//with this my the image name is inserted into my database but not into the foldermy_media/photo
header("Location:imgview.php");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a slash at the end of your path  `$tmp_dir = "my_media/photo/";`?

Comment: i tryed it but still not working

Comment: does the folder photo exist and its writable? as you might have created it with your user but its trying to be written too by www-data..

Comment: i created the folder myself i didn't use code to create that

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $tmp_dir = "/my_media/photo/";
 $name = time().$_FILES["image"]["name"];

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $name);
 $location=$name;
 $fname=$_POST['first_name'];
 $lname=$_POST['last_name'];


 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_image (first_name, last_name, image_location)
 VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$location')";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 header("Location:imgview.php");
}
```

Comment: i have edited my code please check .  and make  the sure  your form  is correct or not      like :   <form action="index.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">.   and submit button name shoul be lowercase name="submit".   check you html properly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, lets remove all `/` and replace them with PHPs `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

```
 $tmp_dir = "my_media". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "photo" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
```

And second, to make sure you have permissions to write to that folder, let PHP create the folder instead.

For this to work, first delete the folder you created.

```
if(!is_dir($tmp_dir)){
  mkdir($tmp_dir);
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$tmp_dir . basename($name));
}else{
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$tmp_dir . basename($name));
}
```

And last but not the least, you are open to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead. [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: it create the folder but still store the image file in my_media and the new created folder remains empty

Comment: @CFrancis try `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "my_media" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "photo" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  basename($name));`

Comment: it only store the name in my database but not the folder am just stock here  I have try all am ask to do but no solution yet what will i do